# Is it posible to create two unidirectional inverse many-to-one associations in GORM

Tags: groovy, grails-orm

I Wonder if there is a possibility to create inverse unidirectional relationships with GORM. I would like to have the following:

```groovy
@Entity User {
   Profile profile // should be unidirectional
}

/* can be edited by any user, though it is owned only by a single user */
@Entity Profile {
   User lastEditedBy // should be unidirectional
}
```

I tried to use the mappedBy-Property in several combinations, but GORM always created a bidirectional association mapping.

Can anyone help me with this Problem?

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: No, not yet. But after analyzing the GORM Code (especially the establishing of Domain Relations in the GormMappingConfigurationStrategy) i think it is not possible.

Comment: Okay.good.Keep it up.